# I need to code the website to show https and remove the .html at the end

Tags: .htaccess

I have recently added a `htaccess` file to my website to get my website to be `https` instead of `http`.

But now I am trying to make my website show `https://sj-design.no/index` instead of showing the html at the end like this `https://sj-design.no/index.html`

How do I get the code to do both in the file?

I also hope the code will remove the html on every underpage in the website.

Comment: I already tried this: #Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: Please do not add additional information in comments to your question. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_ ...